# A Reference for PAC-Bayesian?

Tags: machine-learning, bayesian, pac-learning

I've recently came across topic known as PAC-Bayesian, but I cannot find a source to read about it. Any article that I came across are talking about its application in a specific area but there is no introduction to what it exactly is.

Comment: I'm lately interested in this topic myself, and have been looking for some good sources as well. The most interesting one I found so far is the overview/tutorial paper by David McAllester titled [A PAC-Bayesian Tutorial with A Dropout Bound](http://arxiv.org/abs/1307.2118).

Comment: In addition to the aforementioned materials, I recommend recent materials: 1) [ICML2019 tutorial A Primer on PAC-Bayesian Learning](https://bguedj.github.io/icml2019); 2) [A Primer on PAC-Bayesian Learning](https://arxiv.org/abs/1901.05353); 3) [NIPS 2017 Workshop (Almost) 50 Shades of Bayesian Learning: PAC-Bayesian trends and insights](https://bguedj.github.io/nips2017/50shadesbayesian.html).

Answer (score 6):

Here are a few quick Google hits...

- [PAC-Bayes Analysis: Background and
  Applications](http://www.cse.ohio-state.edu/mlss09/mlss09_talks/1.june-MON/JST_pacbayes-JohnShawe.pdf)
- [Probably Approximately Correct Learning and Vapnik-Chervonenkis Dimension](http://www-edlab.cs.umass.edu/cs589/lectures/week12.pdf)
- [Probably approximately correct learning on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probably_approximately_correct_learning)
- [Overview of the Probably Approximately Correct (PAC) Learning Framework](http://www.cs.iastate.edu/~honavar/pac.pdf)

From this last one, a quote:

> A more refined, Bayesian extension of the PAC model is explored in [26]. Using the Bayesian approach involves assuming a prior distribution over possible target concepts as well as training instances. Given these distributions, the average error of the hypothesis as a function of training sample size, and even as a function of the particular training sample, can be defined. Also, $1 - \delta$ confidence intervals like those in the PAC model can be defined as well.

[26] $=$ W. Buntine, *A Theory of Learning Classification Rules*. PhD thesis, University of Technology, Sydney, 1990.

Answer (score 2):

This paper is a good way to start : https://arxiv.org/pdf/1901.05353.pdf

Comment: Please don't provide link-only answers; eventually, the link will break, and then the answer will be useless.   Providing a link is fine, but you should at least summarize the essentials - and provide the paper's title and author(s) - in the body of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

A more recent elementary introduction to PAC-Bayes

[User-friendly introduction to PAC-Bayes bounds](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2110.11216.pdf)

by Pierre Alquier. It is an 80 page study of this topic.